# Azure SubscriptionClient.PeekBatch

Tags: .net, azure

I am trying to use Azure SubscriptionClient.PeekBatch(int count) to peek at the messages.  All works fine for count values of 0 - 9 but once I enter a value > 9 I only get 9 messages back, there are approx. 30 in the subscription.  Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?  Code sample below;

```
private void PeekQueue(){
  SubscriptionClient subscriptionClient = SubscriptionClient.CreateFromConnectionString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Microsoft.ServiceBus.ConnectionString.Test.Peek"], "InHvccc", "lmo");
  IEnumerable<BrokeredMessage> messages;
  lstMessages.Items.Clear();
  messages = subscriptionClient.PeekBatch(int.Parse(txtPeekCount.Text));
  foreach(BrokeredMessage bm in messages) {
    lstMessages.Items.Add(bm.GetBody<LmoMessage>());
  }
  subscriptionClient.Close();
}
```

Cheers
Stew

Comment: How are you detecting that there are 30 messages in the queue *before or at* the call to `PeekBatch`?

Comment: I sent them to the queue

Comment: did you try the PeekBatch(0,30) overload?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18520714/azure-service-bus-queue-peekbatch-locking) (topic is different, but nice explanation about client and caching), I'd try to play with cache a little bit:

- using PeekBacth(0, 30)
- restart your app and re-try
- restart your cloud service and re-try
- check what happens, when you try to bring less items than last time (for example, ask for 3, 10, and after it - 5)